# How can you set the colors in a chart with Kibana 4?

Tags: kibana-4

I have a stacked bar chart in Kibana 4, and I would like the error bar to be red, the warning bar to be orange and the info bar to be green. This used to be simple to accomplish in Kibana 3, but I cannot figure out how to do it in Kibana 4. Has anyone been able to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be in Kibana 4.4 (already available if you checkout branch 4.4 of kibana instead of downloading the official release). Of course a development branch is not meant to be stable, so use at your own risks.

Answer (score 12):

In kibana4 (at least for v.4.1.0) this is not yet possible. The colors are chosen at random from a defined palette in the code.

Many people are asking for this, and I think it's planned for version 4.3.
You can follow it here: https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/1362